# How to add the Java profile to Papyrus 2.0.0 plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, eclipse-neon, papyrus

Papyrus class diagram has been able to generate Java code by adding "Papyrus profile for Java Models", "Papyrus Java Classes Generator" and "Papyrus Reverse".  In The new Papyrus 2.0.0 there are no packages like above.  So how do I add the "Java registered profile" to the profiles list so I can generate Java code from my UML Class diagram?

Comment: See here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_Code_Generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the "Designer-JAVA" additional component in order to get this functionality.
On the Papyrus toolbar, you should see the Papyrus icon (there are actually two - yes, it can be confusing...). Click on the one that shows the "Install Papyrus Additional Components" tool tip.
In the "Modeler Extensions" section, select the "Designer-JAVA" component and install it. This will download and install the profile, library, and code generation components.
You will then be able to apply both the Papyrus Java and the Papyrus Code Generation profiles.

Added: Note that you can also go through "Help"> "Install Papyrus Additional Components" to install additional components.

Comment: Would you know how to add Java Class stereo types? I don't see it there anymore in Neon!

Comment: The stereotypes need to be loaded to be used. Click on the model's root element to bring up it's Properties view. In the Properties view, click on the Profile tab.

Comment: The rest: The stereotypes need to be loaded to be used. Click on the model's root element to bring up its Properties view. In the Properties view, click on the Profile tab. Select the control to apply a registered profile (the one to the right of the "X"). In the dialogue, select the Papyrus Java profile and click OK. Select all on the next dialogue and then "OK". The profile has been applied to your model and you now have access to the stereotypes. You can also load the library of Java primitives by using the root element's Load Package menu item.